# Merge lines based on first column without delimiter

Tags: awk

I need to merge all the lines that have the same value on the first column.

The input file is the following:

```
34600000031|(1|1|0|1|1|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000031|(2|2|0|2|2|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000031|(3|3|0|3|3|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000031|(4|4|0|4|4|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(1|1|100|1|8|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(2|2|100|2|9|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(3|3|100|3|10|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(4|4|100|4|11|20190114180000|20191027185959)
```

I was able to partially achieve it using the following:

```
awk -F'|' '$1!=p{if(p)print s; p=$1; s=$0; next}{sub(p,x); s=s $0} END{print s}' INPUT
```

The output is the following:

```
34600000031|(1|1|0|1|1|20190114180000|20191027185959)|(2|2|0|2|2|20190114180000|20191027185959)|(3|3|0|3|3|20190114180000|20191027185959)|(4|4|0|4|4|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(1|1|100|1|8|20190114180000|20191027185959)|(2|2|100|2|9|20190114180000|20191027185959)|(3|3|100|3|10|20190114180000|20191027185959)|(4|4|100|4|11|20190114180000|20191027185959)
```

What I need (and i cannot find how) is the following:

```
34600000031|(1|1|0|1|1|20190114180000|20191027185959)(2|2|0|2|2|20190114180000|20191027185959)(3|3|0|3|3|20190114180000|20191027185959)(4|4|0|4|4|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(1|1|100|1|8|20190114180000|20191027185959)(2|2|100|2|9|20190114180000|20191027185959)(3|3|100|3|10|20190114180000|20191027185959)(4|4|100|4|11|20190114180000|20191027185959)
```

I could do a sed after the initial awk but I don't believe that this is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to substitute the separator in the values too. Your fixes awk would look like this:

```
awk -F'|' '$1!=p{if(p)print s; p=$1; s=$0; next}{sub(p "\\|",x); s=s $0} END{print s}'
```

but it's also good to match beginning of the string:

```
awk -F'|' '$1!=p{if(p)print s; p=$1; s=$0; next}{sub("^" p "\\|",x); s=s $0} END{print s}'
```

I would do it somewhat simpler, which uses more memory (as it stores everything in an array) but doesn't need the file to be sorted:

```
awk -F'|' '{ k=$1; sub("^" $1 "\\|", ""); a[k] = a[k] $0 } END{ for (i in a) print i "|" a[i] }'
```

For each line, remember the first field, substitute the first field with `|` for nothing, then add it to an array indexed by the first field. On the end, print each element in the array with the key, separator and value.

Comment: There's 2 practices there that will probably be OK for the posted sample input but in general should be avoided: 1) testing `p` instead of `p!=""` since the former will fail when p is 0 (`NR>1` is a better/clearer test in this context anyway), and 2) `sub(... p or $1 ...,` since using input data in the regexp will produce unexpected results when that input contains re metachars. Also `sub(/.../,x)` where `x` is an unassigned variable and so evaluates to null is needlessly cryptic vs simply using a null string `sub(/.../,"")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    {
        curr = $1
        sub(/^[^|]+\|/,"")
        printf "%s%s", (curr==prev ? "" : ors curr FS), $0
        ors = ORS
        prev = curr
    }
    END { print "" }
' file
34600000031|(1|1|0|1|1|20190114180000|20191027185959)(2|2|0|2|2|20190114180000|20191027185959)(3|3|0|3|3|20190114180000|20191027185959)(4|4|0|4|4|20190114180000|20191027185959)
34600000015|(1|1|100|1|8|20190114180000|20191027185959)(2|2|100|2|9|20190114180000|20191027185959)(3|3|100|3|10|20190114180000|20191027185959)(4|4|100|4|11|20190114180000|20191027185959)
```